# Java, error no suitable method found for add()

Tags: java

I need help with a java problem, when I compile it appears an error, and I already looked in other posts and could not solve if they can help me I will be very grateful.

code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sugestao{
   private int idSugestao;
   private String sugestao;
   private ArrayList<JTextArea> guardaSugestao;

   public Sugestao(){
      guardaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   public Sugestao(int idSugestao){
      this.idSugestao = idSugestao;
      guardaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   public Sugestao(int idSugestao, String sugestao){
      this.idSugestao = idSugestao;
      this.sugestao = sugestao;
      guardaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   public int getIdSugestao(){
      return idSugestao;
   }
   public String getSugestao(){
      return sugestao;
   }
   public ArrayList<JTextArea> guardaSugestao(){
      return guardaSugestao;
   }
   public void setIdSugestao(int idSugestao){
      this.idSugestao = idSugestao;
   }
   public void setSugestao(String sugestao){
      this.sugestao = sugestao;
   }
   public void setGuardaSugestao(ArrayList<JTextArea> guardaSugestao){
      this.guardaSugestao = guardaSugestao;
   }

   public void adicionarSugestao(JTextArea jTextArea){
      guardaSugestao.add(jTextArea);
   }

   public ArrayList<JTextArea> carregaSugestao(Connection conn){
      String sqlSelect = "select id, sugestao from tabelaTeste where id_sugestao = ?";
      ArrayList<JTextArea> listaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();

      try(PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);){
         stm.setInt(1, getIdSugestao());
         try(ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();){
            while(rs.next()){
               Sugestao s = new Sugestao();
               s.setIdSugestao(rs.getInt("id_sugestao"));
               s.setSugestao(rs.getString("sugestao")); 
               listaSugestao.add(s); // error
            }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         catch(SQLException e1){
            System.out.print(e1.getStackTrace());
         }
         return listaSugestao;
      }
   }
    public String toString() {
        return "Sugestao [id=" + idSugestao + ", sugestao :" + sugestao + "]";
    }
}
```

This is the error that appears, I do not know how to solve.

```
error: no suitable method found for add(Sugestao)
```

Comment: What line does the error appear on?

Comment: use `xx=new ArrayList<JTextArea>();` instead of `xx=new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: `ArrayList<JTextArea> listaSugestao ... Sugestao s ... listaSugestao.add(s)` ...

Comment: @XtremeBaumer what should that accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

The error appears because of your `listaSugestao` declaration. It is an ArrayList of type `JTextArea`, which only accepts `JTextArea` objects and you try to add a `Sugestao` object to it. You need to change the ArrayList declaration to be an ArrayList of type `Sugestao`.

Change this line:

```
  ArrayList<JTextArea> listaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();
```

to this:

```
  ArrayList<Sugestao> listaSugestao = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do the rest of the code kk

Compiled

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, your arraylist is taking `JTextArea` type as you have declared it as `ArrayList<JTextArea> guardaSugestao;`
So, it needs to be changed as

```
ArrayList<Sugestao> guardaSugestao;
```

so that it takes `Sugestao` types into the list.

Also, ensure that your methods `setGuardaSugestao()`, `guardaSugestao()`, `adicionarSugestao()` are changed accordingly to accept `ArrayList<Sugestao>`

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do the rest of the code kk

Compiled

Answer (score 0):

`listaSugestao` expects elements of type `JTextArea`.
But in `listaSugestao.add(s);` your variable `s` is of type `Sugestao`.

Simply change the type of `ArrayList<JTextArea>` to `ArrayList<Sugestao>` and **also** the method definition from `public ArrayList<JTextArea> carregaSugestao(Connection conn)` to `public ArrayList<Sugestao> carregaSugestao(Connection conn)` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do the rest of the code kk

Compiled