# 'No suitable method found for add(Circle)' error

Tags: java, object, javafx

I'm beginning to learn JavaFX, so I'm struggling to figure out what is wrong with this code.

```
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
public class CirclePane extends HBox
{
   private int numCircles;
   private Color fill;

   public CirclePane(Color c)
   {
      this(1,c);   
   }
   public CirclePane(int numCircles, Color c)
   {
    this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    this.setPrefSize(100,100);
    this.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 5;" +
                  "-fx-border-color: black;");
    for (int i = 0; i < numCircles; i++)
       this.getChildren().add(new Circle(10,"black"));
    fill = c;
    this.numCircles = numCircles;



   }
   public Color getFill()
   {
      return fill;
   }
   public int getNumCircles()
   {
      return numCircles;
   }


}
```

I'm receiving:

> "error: no suitable method found for add(Circle)"

on:

```
   this.getChildren().add(new Circle(10,"black"));
```

Also, the error is followed by:

> method Collection.add(Node) is not applicable (argument mismatch;
>   Circle cannot be converted to Node).

As I'm not sure where the error is coming from, I'm struggling with how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, error no suitable method found for add()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604762/java-error-no-suitable-method-found-for-add)

Comment: hmm .. what is Circle? Don't see any import .. and the constructor taking a String as parameter looks fishy ..

Comment: Did you create your own `Circle` class in the same package as the `CirclePane` class that does not extend `Node` or one of it's subtypes? You do not import `javafx.scene.shape.Circle`; also that class does not take a `String` as constructor parameter...